# What are pangrams used for?

Tags: word-usage, sentence, syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns

The sentence "*the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog*" uses every letter in the English alphabet. What is the main usage of these *pangrams*?

Comment: While certainly not the main usage, I employed panagrams to teach students how to use arrays in a comp sci 101 class.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The main usage today is that you can see how all letters of a certain font look like. It's been in use ever since we have GUIs (Graphical User Interfaces) instead of just CLIs (Command Line Interfaces) with a fixed font.

Of course, you can just display the alphabet, but that doesn't look like normal text and will be perceived differently by a reader. It's use is therefore related to [Lorem ipsum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum).

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram), it was used in the days of the Telex already, to test if all letters could be broadcasted and received over a communication channel.

Comment: Anecdotally, it was also used in pre-computer/Teletext days in typing schools to ensure that the students used every key on the (then manual) keyboard; both my mother and my wife remember typing it quite frequently.

Comment: As a child in the 50s my qualified typist mother told me that _the quick brown fox..._ was used by typewriter mechanics to test the mechanism. The point being that using the pangram was a more realistic text than carefully pressing every key without typing words.

Comment: I recall seeing books of printing font samples employing that line (and also "How does one assess and evaluate a type face...") back in the mid 60s, well before computerized printing.